# Dispose a Shell without dispose the Display (parent)

Tags: java, swt

I've a problem with a Java Project, using SWT library. It's my first time trying with SWT, so don't throw stones to me please.

Environment: Eclipse - Juno

Class and functions:

1º Client -> Where's "main". Creates a object of "GUI_Creator" class (mine).

2º GUI_Creator -> Has 2 functions, in order to "desing" my forms.

2.1 -> MakeLogIn -> Void method, wich adds the controls i need to the Shell i give him as parameter. I use it, to desing the first form i show to the user.

This function also link the "click" event of a button of this shell, with the second function of GUI_Creator class, that creates a new one shell. Then, this shell would be open, and first one would be closed.

2.2 -> MakeClient -> This function returns a shell var. For me, this returns the second shell of my program, even with the desing, etc.

Problem:

I'm using, at the end of "main" this code:

```
while (!Conexion.isDisposed())
{
   if (!ourDisplay.readAndDispatch())
      ourDisplay.sleep();
}

ourDisplay.dispose();
```

If i'm not wrong, this code is doing that when i try to close my first shell, and then leave only opened the second shell, my program closes completely, because i'm disposing the parent display.

However, i can't delete this code, because if i do this, when i run my program, it doesn't "wait" an action, and just executes all "main" code and then closes the GUI and the program finalizes.

So, i really don't know what would i have to do, in order to fix this situation.

Thanks,
Btc

Comment: Can you write a short, self contained, complete, and correct example? http://sscce.org/ The example you gave is not self contained, nor complete, so it's hard to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your problem right, but you could try:

```
while (!(shell1.isDisposed() && shell2.isDisposed())) {
...
}
```

Comment: Solved!! Thanks!! I have a Little problem because i hasn't the Shell var of the second Shell at "main", but this wasn't important.